# I'm playing a game where I'm tossing a fair coin. When it's heads I gain a dollar. When it's tails I lose a dollar. I play until I have +24 or -36

Tags: binomial-distribution

I'm playing a game where I'm tossing a fair coin. When it's heads I gain a dollar. When it's tails I lose a dollar. I play until I have +24 or -36. What's the probability of each condition?

I'm comparing answers to chatgpt.

Comment: MathOverflow is not for you to harvest answers, especially if you do not intend to engage with the content but merely compare them to a chatbot.

Comment: I've found my answer by running excel simulations. It appears the answer is simply 36/60 and 24/60. Chatgpt could not provide a satisfactory answer.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin#Fair_coin_flipping) or any good textbook would give you the answer.  You have a fair coin and thus a martingale, so with any [stopping rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopping_time)  the expected position will always be $0$.  So you need the probabilities to enable $24 \times \frac{36}{24+36}-36\times \frac{24}{24+36}=0$

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to simulate to get the answers.

- The ambit of the game is $24-(-36) =60$
- Since the odds are even, the up/down relationship will be linear, and  the two ends represent the extremities of a straight line
- It is evident that the nearer you are to your goal, the higher your probability of achieving it.
- Thus the probability of success is equal to the fraction of the ambit from ruin, and vice-versa.
- You can solve any gambler's ruin problem with even odds similarly.